# Finding a covariance of discrete rv

Tags: probability

> Suppose you are given a fair die and you roll it 6 times. Let $X$ be
> the number of times a $1$ is observed. Let $Y$ be the number of times
> a $6$ is observed. Please, find $\mathrm{cov}(X,Y)$.

### Try

First of all $E(XY)=0$ since there is no way to observe a $6$ and a $1$ at the same time. Thus, all we need to compute is $E(X)$ and $E(Y)$. We can find the mass function of both indiviaully since they both take values from $0$ to $6$ or we can write $X_i$ to be $1$ if a 1 is observed in the ith roll and so $X=X_1+X_2+...+X_6$. So

$E(X) = \sum^6 E(X_i) $

and $E(X_i) = P(X_i=1)= \frac{1}{6} $. Hence, $E(X)=1$. Simiarly, $E(Y)=1$. Therefore, $cov(X,Y)=-1$.

Is this answer correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the joint probability table (all in-table entries must be divided by $6^6$):
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c}
Y/X&0&1&2&\color{red}3&4&5&6\\
\hline
0&{6\choose 0}{5\choose 0}4^6&{6\choose 1}{5\choose 0}4^5&{6\choose 2}{4\choose 0}4^4&{6\choose 3}{3\choose 0}4^3&{6\choose 4}{2\choose 0}4^2&{6\choose 5}{1\choose 0}4^1&{6\choose 6}{0\choose 0}4^0\\
\hline
\color{blue}1&{6\choose 0}{6\choose 1}4^5&{6\choose 1}{5\choose 1}4^4&{6\choose 2}{4\choose 1}4^3&{6\choose \color{red}3}{3\choose \color{blue}1}4^2&{6\choose 4}{2\choose 1}4^1&{6\choose 5}{1\choose 1}4^0&0\\
\hline
2&{6\choose 0}{6\choose 2}4^4&{6\choose 1}{5\choose 2}4^3&{6\choose 2}{4\choose 2}4^2&{6\choose 3}{3\choose 2}4^1&{6\choose 4}{2\choose 2}4^0&0&0\\
\hline
3&{6\choose 0}{6\choose 3}4^3&{6\choose 1}{5\choose 3}4^2&{6\choose 2}{4\choose 3}4^1&{6\choose 3}{3\choose 3}4^0&0&0&0\\
\hline
4&{6\choose 0}{6\choose 4}4^2&{6\choose 1}{5\choose 4}4^1&{6\choose 2}{4\choose 4}4^0&0&0&0&0\\
\hline
5&{6\choose 0}{6\choose 5}4^1&{6\choose 1}{5\choose 5}4^0&0&0&0&0&0\\
\hline
6&{6\choose 0}{6\choose 6}4^0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
\end{array}$$
**Explanation of finding the probability $P(X=3 \ \& \ Y=1)$:**

There are $6^6$ ways to get $6$ numbers in $6$ rolls: $6\cdot 6\cdot 6\cdot6\cdot6\cdot6=6^6$.

There are ${6\choose 3}$ ways to get $3$ numbers $1$ in $6$ rolls, then there are ${3\choose 1}$ ways to get $1$ number $6$ in $3$ rolls and then there are $4^2$ ways to get the numbers $2,3,4,5$ in $2$ rolls (i.e. $4\cdot 4=4^2$).

So:
$$P(X=3 \ \& \ Y=1)=\frac1{6^6} {6\choose 3}{3\choose 1}4^2=0.02.$$

**The expected value of $XY$ is:**
$$\mathbb E(XY)=\frac1{6^6}\sum_{i=0}^6\sum_{j=0}^6 X_iY_i\cdot \mathbb P(X=X_i \ \text{and} \ Y=Y_j)=\\
\frac1{6^6}\left[0\cdot 0\cdot {6\choose 0}{5\choose 0}\cdot 4^6+0\cdot 1\cdot {6\choose 1}{5\choose 0}\cdot 4^5+\cdots+6\cdot 0\cdot {6\choose 0}{6\choose 6}\cdot 4^0+0\right]=\frac56.$$
Hence:
$$\mathsf{Cov}(X,Y) = \mathbb E[XY] - \mathbb E[X]\mathbb E[Y] =\frac56-1\cdot 1=-\frac16.$$

Comment: Sorry wait. I am afraid the probabilities must be slightly different. For example, $P(1,1)={6\choose 1}{5\choose 1}\cdot 4^4$, etc. I’ll fix it in the morning. Good night. Math1000's answer looks correct but not sure about $(6-i-j)^4$ term, I think it should be $4^{6-i-j}$. So, wait before accepting.

Comment: I've updated my answer as promised. Note that it must be $P(1,1)=\color{red}{\frac1{6^6}}{6\choose 1}{5\choose 1}\cdot 4^4$ in my previous comment. The same applies to all in-table entries. I just wanted to keep the table as concise as possible. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

$X$ and $Y$ are each binomially distributed with parameters $n=6$ and $p=1/6$, so $\mathbb E[X]=\mathbb E[Y]=6\cdot1/6=1$. However, $X$ and $Y$ are not independent, since for example observing $6$ ones means that there can be no sixes observed. Indeed, if $i$ ones are observed, then at most $6-i$ sixes can be observed. Rolling a die six times has $6^6$ outcomes, each with probability $1/6^6$, so summing over $i$ ones and $j$ sixes yields
$$
\mathbb E[XY] = \left(1/6^6\right)\sum_{i=0}^6\sum_{j=0}^{6-i}ij\binom 6i\binom{6-i}j 4^{6-i-j} = \frac56.
$$
The covariance is hence
$$
\mathsf{Cov}(X,Y) = \mathbb E[XY] - \mathbb E[X]\mathbb E[Y] = \frac56 - 1\cdot 1 = -\frac16.
$$

Comment: Good! you did what I asked the OP to do.

Comment: +1. It is a good solution, however, I think the term $(6-i-j)^4$ must be $4^{6-i-j}$, because the [first](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F6%5E6*sum(i%3D0+to+6)sum(j+%3D0+to+6-i)+i*j*binom(6,i)*binom(6-i,j)*(6-i-j)%5E4) is undefined and the [second](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F6%5E6*sum(i%3D0+to+6)sum(j+%3D0+to+6-i)+i*j*binom(6,i)*binom(6-i,j)*4%5E(6-i-j)) gives the same answer as mine. Regards.

Comment: @farruhota Thanks for pointing out my error.

Comment: You are welcome. I wonder how you found $275/324$, now it must be $5/6$. See the links in my previuos comment. Good luck.

Comment: Indeed, that would be a result of not fully correcting my answer :)